# Multiple views under NestedScrollview and SwipeRefreshLayout (issue with scroll)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-nestedscrollview

So I have the following design in mind, and what I want is that all the elements scroll together smoothly and also have support for swipe to refresh.

[image]

I have tested the following xml in Android 4.4.4 and it works perfectly. The scroll is fast and smooth and all is well! However when I deploy it on Android 7.1.1, scrolling becomes really laggy and most of the time it stops when you remove your finger, instead of slowing down..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>


<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/myScrollView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:src="@drawable/mypicture"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:id="@+id/top1pic" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="230dp"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient_home_50">

                <TextView
                    android:text="Hello"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="27sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView3" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="you are"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="19sp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/textView3"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/textView5" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/textView3"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/textView5"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/rhome"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:id="@+id/number1pic" />

            </RelativeLayout>


            <Space
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/top1pic"
                android:id="@+id/uselessSpace"/>

            <TextView
                android:text="Sup"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/uselessSpace"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/textView1" />

            <TextView
                android:text="mpla mpla"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
                android:id="@+id/textView10" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/horizontalRecycler"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/numberOfPeopleHere"
                android:minHeight="200dp"
                android:maxHeight="200dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:text="mpla mpla"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/horizontalRecycler"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/textView4" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/homelist"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/textView4"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:paddingBottom="48dp"
                android:maxHeight="200dp"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_above="@id/homelist"
                android:id="@+id/uselessSpace2"
                android:visibility="gone"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/progressbarlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ProgressBar
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Small"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="All good?"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
    <!--android:layout_weight="138.70"
    (was in textview above)-->
</LinearLayout>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
    style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
    android:shadowRadius="3"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Also I have added the following lines to the main class of the fragment:

```
// for the vertical RecyclerView
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.homelist);

recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false) {
            @Override
            public boolean canScrollVertically() {
                return false;
            }
});

recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

// for the horizontal RecyclerView    
RHRNRecycler = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.horizontalRecycler);
RHRNRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false) {
            @Override
            public boolean canScrollVertically() {
                return false;
            }
});
```

So has something changed with NestedScrollView during all these versions, which means that I have to change completely the way I implement this design?  Is there actually a better way to do this (Standard-wise)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who is still looking at this post, what I did was put everything in a single recyclerview (first cell had the "imageview and some relative elements", second cell had the horizontal recyclerview and from the third on the data of the vertical one).

This however did not fix the smooth scroll problem. What I found out is that in the vertical one, I was using some images (drawables) that were too large, so they had to be scaled down during runtime, thus causing slowdown.

My tip on that is use a caching image loading library whenever you can ([Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) is great!) for example when downloading from internet. Also when you want to load images from a drawable (using 'android:src' in xml) be sure to utilize the different drawable folders that android provides. That can really help performance-wise!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the next line?

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```